# Как обработать многомерный массив в js?

Tags: javascript, массивы

есть массив `filesArr` которые содержит в себе элементы по порядку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как достать из первого уровня, названия, которые хранятся под нулевым ключем?
Например как `recomendation`?

Пробовал вот такие образом:

```
$(filesArr).each(function(i, item){
        console.log(item[0]);
});
```

но выдает `undefined`

извините за скрины, не получилось, воспроизвести подобный массив.

i это счетчик отправляемых файлов

таким образом данные отправляю и принимаю с сервера

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/poc/"+controller,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response){
//после каждой загрузки файла response ={"file_name":"1a80c8b71a346814915a7d185c604067.png","input_name":"recommendation[1]"}
                var result = $.parseJSON(response);
                var clearInput_name = result.input_name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, '');
                var clearInput_name_num = parseInt(result.input_name.match(/\d+/));
                filesArr[i].push(clearInput_name);
                filesArr[i].push(result.file_name);
                filesArr[i].push(clearInput_name_num);
            }
```

Comment: Но вы можете этот массив вручную создать и добавить в код вопроса (заодно и полноценный сниппет получится). Иначе создавать массив придётся отвечающему, что совсем не здорово.

Comment: А вообще, кстати, несмотря на крайне спорное использование jQuery здесь, код выглядит рабочим. Может, у вас внутренние массивы позже (вывода) заполняются?

Comment: Regent, если не использую, то each не распознает, выводит сообщение что такой функции нет, может быть это связано что массив приходит с сервера? и когда я пытаюсь его парсить он еще не сформирован?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов приложите тогда весь код, и тот где вы получаете этот массив

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов в jQuery - `.each(function(index, value`, в самом JS - `.forEach(function(value, index`. С обработкой асинхронного ответа от сервера ошибка весьма распространена, но чтобы сказать наверняка, нужно увидеть ваш код получения ответа и как он связан с представленным в вопросе кодом.

Comment: @ThisMan "приложите весь код" - рискованное заявление. Хотелось бы вместо тонны кода минимального воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: @Regent согласен, скорее всего здесь вопрос в асинхронности, ибо видно, что изначально все массивы в массиве имеют 0 элементов, а затем мутируют.

Comment: @Regent, да дело было в том что данные приходят асинхронно, не подскажите как обойти? как отследить кода данные получены? 
сейчас перебор засунул в setTimeout в ajax использую success, думал этого достаточно

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов есть [специальный вопрос-справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/183458), там подробно расписано что с этим всем можно сделать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 2):

```
filesArr.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item[0]);
});
```

Comment: Это никак не решает проблему автора.